# Email notification on events - Oracle Queue

Tags: java, oracle, jms, oracle11g, tomcat6

I've events table in Oracle database. I want to send email notification whenever a record is inserted into Oracle table. I'm using Tomcat & I don't have JMS or any other support.

I need to finish this in next 2.5 weeks.

Can I use Oracle Advanced Queuing in which Oracle will enqueue the data from events table? But I'm not sure if I can dequeu it with standalone Java Program?

Can any one recommend me some ways to achieve this with a sample example?

Note: I've to use JAVA only as its a requirement for us.

Thanks

Comment: Are you allowed to use plsql ?

Comment: yes. But I was thinking of writing standalone java program which will get the message from the queue & then I can send email. I'm not sure if this can be done or not. But here is the link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/apexampl.htm#59717      I can have a thread running which will be performing dequeue the way its shown in this example. Can someone tell me if I can do it with way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done it, but you can use Oracle AQ from Java directly. Worst case, you could write some PLSQL to dequeue the next message and call that standard stored procedure from Java. Try googling for oracle AQ java.

For your problem, I would either use a trigger to place a message on the queue everytime a row is inserted into the table, or change the API used to insert into the table to also enqueue a message onto the queue.

Then you could have a separate process that reads each message from the queue and sends the email.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use Java to send the email?  In the past I've used UTL_MAIL and a trigger to send emails from within the database when a row has been inserted.

You would need to create a process to send the email, possible using dbms_scheduler.  AQ was a cost option at the time so I didn't use it.

[ULT_MAIL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm)
[DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm)
[Example showing how to send an email](http://oraclepitstop.wordpress.com/2008/04/24/how-to-send-email-from-10g-oracle-database-utl_mail/)

You will need to get UTL_MAIL instaled in the Oralce Database as it's not part of the default install and, depending on the configuration of you mail server, have the database added to you list of 'safe senders'

Answer (score 0):

one of the simpler ways to get it done is to create an INSERT trigger on that table, that will  make a call to the email stored proc to email notification. of course you have to work with your email administrator to work out the proper email server address/name to use - if exchange use mail. as an example. if you need assistance with the scripts let me know via this post.

Answer (score 0):

Using Oracle AQ will be much easier to do the task.
Check the link -

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/apexampl.htm#59717